# How do i run Wald/Score/Likelihood Ratio Test in R with only one vector?

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I've calculated the test statistics by hand, but want to confirm that my answer is correct. I don't know where to start, after assigning the vector values.

With large sample, the Wald test statistic, score test statistic, and likelihood ratio test statistic approximately have the chisquare df=1 distribution. Y~Binomial (1,pi) with P(Y=1)=pi and P(Y=0)=1-pi. Observations Yi, i = 1 to m are iid as Y.

For m = 10, and data (0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), use these statistics to test the null hypothesis pi=0.3.

Disclaimer: Although this is homework related, the R-part is not part of the homework. I'm curious as to whether I can run this problem in R to confirm my answers.

Comment: check `?prop.test` and `?glm` ... ?

Comment: Have you done any research into how to do this in R yourself? You should check this out... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I know I can run `glm` when I have the dependent variable and at least one independent variable, and it will produce these test statistics. However, how do I get the statistics if there's only one vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put in a "1" to represent a constant term in your glm.

```
x=c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
glm(x~1)
```

This is equivalent to fitting a GLM with no data, just an intercept.

Comment: That would be a test for pi=0.5

Comment: Thank you, this makes so much sense!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an offset term that represents your null hypothesis on the logg-odds scale:

```
glm( dat ~ offset(rep(log(0.3/0.7),10)), family=binomial)

Call:  glm(formula = dat ~ offset(rep(log(0.3/0.7), 10)), family = binomial)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
   1.17e-12  

Degrees of Freedom: 9 Total (i.e. Null);  9 Residual
Null Deviance:      12.22 
Residual Deviance: 12.22    AIC: 14.22
```

The intercept estimate is essentially 0 since the observed odds are at teh hypothesized value; however, the number of events is so small that statistical significance at conventional levels would be unlikely to be established no matter what the outcome. The p-value is the probability that the data does not fit the hypothesized value, whereas in this case it does.